# Difference between save and sneaky_save in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save

What is the difference between save and sneaky_save in rails?

`object.save`
and 
`object.sneaky_save`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`save` - is `ActiveRecord` method,
`sneaky_save` - is a method from the gem [sneaky-save](https://github.com/einzige/sneaky-save). It's a ActiveRecord extension, that allows saving records without calling callbacks and validations.

Comment: The sneaky-save gem does not work with Rails 5.2 and above.